# how to set yii required field in request page only but not create/update?

Tags: php, yii

Is there any one know what should I do so that users are required to fill in the input in request page only but not in create/update page? I had my own reason I want to do like that.

In User Model

```
array('user_email, user_name', 'required','on'=>'request'),  //I want this only occur when on my request page
```

In User Controller

```
public function actionRequest()
{
    $id=Yii::app()->user->uid;
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if ($model->validate('request')) 
        {
            if($model->save())
            {
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$uid));
            }
        }
    }

    $this->render('request',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

But somehow this does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to create your model with the `scenario` so that the rules applicable to that `scenario` can be applied.

Let's say your `scenario` is `some_scenario`, then when you declare the `rules` use like so:

```
array('user_email, user_name', 'required', 'on'=>'some_scenario')
// now the user_email, user_name will be required properties only when the scenario is 'some_scenario'
```

Now to apply a scenario to a model we have to create that model instance with that scenario, like so:

```
$model = new SomeModel('some_scenario');
```

[Here's a yii wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) that you might want to read.

**Edit:** In your case you can set the `scenario` after the model object is created, by directly setting the [`scenario` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#scenario-detail):

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id);
$model->scenario = 'request';

// ...
```

Comment: assumed that you didn't declare the model with your scenario name, if that's not the case, do comment

Comment: $model = new SomeModel('some_scenario'); is it I should put this line in User controller?

Comment: can you please refer to my edited post?

Comment: Add `$model->scenario = 'request';` just before the line with `$model->attributes = $_POST['User'];`

Comment: n3lSe, sorry was a.f.k. have added details to answer, i think it'll be better to have that line before the `if` incase you want to go for scenario specific attribute labels. @WillemRenzema thanks! and wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @bool.dev thanks to u as well!! have a nice day~

Comment: @bool.dev Yeah, that works too. I don't use scenario specific labels, so didn't think of that, but in general putting it right after the declaration of the model is best, as you suggested.